# I can run ubuntu in recovery mode fine, but when I run in normal mode it hangs

Tags: recovery-mode

Why does ubuntu hang in normal mode but runs fine in recovery mode ?

Comment: Can you be more specific? In what way does it hang?

Comment: the mouse and keyboard are frozen so I am assuming its hung. I consistently get this when I run the "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic" and the "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (upstart)" options. But when I run the "Ubuntu, with Linux 4.4.0-31-generic (recovery mode)" everything is fine.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your post, when you want to add information? It’s best to have everything relevant in one place. Additionally, comments may be deleted for various reasons.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue a week ago. it might be a kernel bug, what i did is re-installed ubuntu with 16.04 LTS and now everything is fine with keyboard & mouse. try apt-get update to update everything if that didn't worked, try reinstalling your OS.

Comment: In general the last thing to suggest is to reinstall the OS, but a kernel bug is a serious matter, so it's OK to suggest that here, especially if you can find the report of the possible kernel bug on the Launchpad bug tracker.

Comment: Tried reinstalling, but no difference. It boots fine and connects to the internet, all is well, browser works, then after five minutes or so hangs. Any way I could trap the error before it hangs ?

Comment: Do you think its a disk error ? Any way I can run a chkdsk in ubuntu ?